# SQL - grouping transactions also grouping shop names

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT frs_Employee.empnin, empname, COUNT( frs_Payment.empnin ) AS Transaction
FROM frs_Employee, frs_Payment
GROUP BY frs_Payment.empnin
```

When I compile this, it gives me the same name, but the correct numbers. How could I make the names differ?

Comment: Unclear.  Show the table details, sample data, and what you want the results to look like.

Comment: `FROM frs_Employee, frs_Payment` this is cross join you probably need `inner join` with specified condition but your question is missing details

Comment: include empname on the group by line?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables on empnin. You'll also need to add empname to the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT frs_Employee.empnin
       , empname
       , COUNT( frs_Payment.empnin ) AS Transaction
FROM frs_Employee, 
INNER JOIN frs_Payment on frs_Payment.empnin = frs_Employee.empnin
GROUP BY frs_Employee.empnin, empname
```